# Как избежать округления DECIMAL при запросе SELECT SUM?

Tags: sql, mariadb

`MariaDB 10.6`.

Создал следующую функцию:

```
CREATE
    FUNCTION count_sum()
    RETURNS DECIMAL(19, 3)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.000;

    SET result = (SELECT SUM(ba.amount) FROM billing_account AS ba);
    RETURN result;
END;
```

Здесь поле `billing_account.amount` имеет тип `DECIMAL(19, 3)`. Однако, в результате вызова функции я получаю округлённое целочисленное значение. Каким образом я могу избежать округления, чтобы получить точное число с долями?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/2le3Op_4 - работает. Обрезание не в клиенте? Ищите в чем у вас отличие от этого простейшего рабочего примера

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA извините, тут моя ошибка. Не указал весь код полностью, там довольно большой скрипт. Да, дело было в том что устанавливал полученное значение в переменную с типом DECIMAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в sum. Если тип просто `DECIMAL`, то в нем [не хранится](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/decimal/) дробная часть (по умолчанию хранится 0 знаков после запятой). Используйте DECIMAL(32, 4) чтоб хранить 4 знака после запятой.

При вставке нецелых чисел в колонку типа `DECIMAL` значение обрезается и выдается предупреждение:

`Data truncated for column`

Такое же обрезание происходит, если присвоить значение переменной с типом DECIMAL, как в вашем случае.